# Where is Gendry now? Did I miss something? Are characters assumed alive until shown / told dead?

Tags: game-of-thrones

What happened after he passed out in Davos' arms after his marathon run?  Did he die from exhaustion?  Recover and stay at Eastwatch to fight with Tormund and Beric?  Get dropped off at / run to Winterfell?  Dropped off at Dragonstone to forge weapons?  I don't think he'd go back to KL, he wants to fight.  Is there something about his contract making him too expensive to include in scenes, like Ghost?

Also concerned about Tormund being alive (Beric can die,) couldn't tell if they survived the collapse of the wall.

Is the idea that everyone's alive unless we're shown their death or told they were killed?

Comment: This will be answered in future, therefore it will be put on hold, for now, in adherence with our [Future Works Policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based). You have done well to make sure this meets the site's quality standards, however, if you want an answer here, you'll have to wait.

Comment: [Coincidence?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/where-is-gendry)

Comment: Is it like they want to keep him hidden?  I was just trying to figure out if he's dead now at Eastwatch with the wall falling down, or will be with the dead walking through, or if he's smithing at Dragonstone, or we just didn't see him in KL.

Comment: He'd most likely be at Winterfell to be honest. Or wherever Davos is.

Comment: I was thinking he might be headed to WF, too, but it would be a long walk, and I think he's looking for more of a fight, so staying at Eastwatch with Beric and Tormund made more sense to me, we just didn't see him.

Comment: Training for the next marathon?

Comment: Back to rowing, very likely.

Comment: My guess would be forging weapons out of Dragonglass either in Eastwatch or at Winterfell. (But possibly also Castle Black)

Comment: He's running....

Comment: @Möoz: Davos went to Kings Landing eh. I don’t think we saw Gendry in that particular party, but presumably he accompanied Davos on the boat back to Dragonstone before they all went to Kings Landing. (Unless they went directly from Eastwatch to Kings Landing.)

Comment: He could be in Dorne or Essos based on his disclosed ultra-marathon ability and/or Westeros' secret rapid transport system...

Comment: @paul you're right mate, forgot because he basically had not point in being there.

Comment: Awkward moment if he decides to go North, beyond the Wall and all the way up where the Night King doesn't realise he's there! LOL

Comment: I picture him Forrest Gump'ing his way through Essos, where he has more area to cover